# how to put Custom Next and Prev Scroll Buttons for div react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have two buttons. `Prev` and `Next` Button. On below, I have one `horizontal div` with multiple items with `scroll bar`.

Here's the UI looks like:

[image]

The Scroll Bar working good. But I have prev and next buttons. When I click on two buttons, it should scroll left and right. I tried. But I don't know how to make it in react.

Here's the Code I tried:

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          gap: "50px",
          marginBottom: "30px"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Prev</div>
        <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Next</div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          gap: "150px",
          overflow: "scroll",
          backgroundColor: "aqua"
        }}
      >
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div>item {item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't know how to make it. Please help me with some solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scrollLeft property and useRef. Here is my solution.

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
  const ref = React.useRef(null)

  const handleScroll = (offset) => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.scrollLeft += offset;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          gap: "50px",
          marginBottom: "30px"
        }}
      >
        <div onClick={() => handleScroll(-30)} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Prev</div>
        <div onClick={() => handleScroll(30)} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Next</div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          gap: "150px",
          overflow: "scroll",
          backgroundColor: "aqua"
        }}
        ref={ref}
      >
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>item {item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated slick slider api

```
  const sliderRef = useRef();

  const handleScroll = (direction) => {
    if (sliderRef.current) {
      if (direction === "right") sliderRef.current.slickPrev();
      if (direction === "left") sliderRef.current.slickNext();
    }
  };
```